# How to save current user_id to database (YII2)

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-user

I try to save current user_id to the education table in database. However,the data of user_id is not filled. This is my code.

At model

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['year', 'fieldstudy', 'institute', 'grade'], 'required'],
        [['user_id'], 'integer'],
        [['year', 'fieldstudy', 'institute', 'grade'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
    ];
}


public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'education_id' => 'Education ID',
        'user_id' => 'User ID',
        'year' => 'Year',
        'fieldstudy' => 'Fieldstudy',
        'institute' => 'Institute',
        'grade' => 'Grade',
    ];
}

public function getUser()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['user_id' => 'user_id']);
}
```

At controller

```
     public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Education();
    $model->user_id =Yii::$app->user->id;

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {

        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->education_id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

How can I solve my problem and fix my code? Thanks

Comment: try Yii::$app->user->user_id

Comment: The new Educatiion instance is saved  in db without che proper code for user_id or is not saved ?

Answer (score 0):

update `Yii::$app->user->id` to `Yii::$app->user->identity->id`.

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Education();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $model->user_id =Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
        if($model->save()){
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->education_id]);
        } 
        }
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
    }
```

Comment: The value  at column user_id still 0. @jithin

Comment: It  goes to blank page..@jithin

Comment: @Fyp16 can u try it now

Comment: I've try it. The column user_id still 0.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check two things

1. Check whether the user is logged in.
2. Use Yii2 debugger to see whether we are getting the id value of the logged in user by the code `Yii::$app->user->id` or `Yii::$app->user->id`

Use Yii2 debugger to check whether the correct user id value we are getting by using the code

```
Yii::info("User id=".Yii::$app->user->id);
```

Full code you have to try in the controller is given below

```
 public function actionCreate() {
        $model = new Education();

        //checking whether we are getting the logged in user id value
        Yii::info("User id=".Yii::$app->user->id); 

        $model->user_id = Yii::$app->user->id;

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {

             //checking here the saved user id value in  table
             Yii::info("checking User id after saving model=".$model->user_id); 

            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->education_id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                        'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Now after running the application you can check using Yii2 debugger the values that are set in the user id in various places.

Comment: the column user_id still 0 @ajith